# Hide every element under a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way I can hide each `<p></p>` and show `<h1></h1>` instead on click of a button (`onclick="javascript hide <p> show <h1>`), and vise versa. I could do it with unique id but I cannot assign the same id for each. Is there any way to do it? preferably without jquery.

```html
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

Here I add an event listener to a button.

I hid each p first, since I assume you want to show the title when the page loads.

Alternatively hide the Ps onload using script when loading the page:

```
allP.forEach(p => p.hidden = true);
```

Note: that will show the p's while the page loads, but then again that also shows the user that there is data under each title

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const allP = document.querySelectorAll(".SubTitle p");
  const allH = document.querySelectorAll(".SubTitle h1");
  // allP.forEach(p => p.hidden = true);
  document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    allP.forEach(p => p.hidden = !p.hidden);
    allH.forEach(h => h.hidden = !h.hidden);
  })
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p hidden>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p hidden>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p hidden>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css selector `>` for direct child of, and say that the direct child `p` elements of `div` elements are all toggled the hidden class when the button is clicked. You could target more specifically with `div > div > p` or `.SubTitle > p` as well.

```js
document.getElementById("p").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("div > p")
    .forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("hidden"));
});
document.getElementById("h1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("div > h1")
    .forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("hidden"));
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="p">toggle p</button>
<button id="h1">toggle h1</button>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p>Text</p>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Title">
  <div class="SubTitle">
    <p>Text</p> 
    <h1>Text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not cache the elements. Your code will read through the page for elements on every click. Also OP asked for one button to toggle between p and h1